# Automatically Deactivate Plugin After a Check

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to get my Wordpress plugin to deactivate automatically after a simple check. It seems to be calling the admin_notices method just fine, but the deactivate_plugin() method does not do anything. This is in the class constructor:

```
        // End if the theme isn't compatible
        if ( FALSE == $this->themesupport['support'] ) { // This test works fine

            add_action( 'admin_init',       array( &$this, 'deactivate_plugin' ) ); // Plugin doesn't deactivate
            add_action( 'admin_notices',    array( &$this, 'admin_notices' ) ); // I get notices

            if ( isset( $_GET['activate'] ) )
                unset( $_GET['activate'] );

            return;

        } // if()
```

The method is pretty straightforward:

```
public function deactivate_plugin() {

                deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );

        } // deactivate_plugin()
```

Putting an echo in that deactivate_plugin method and it gets called. I've also tried including the plugins.php file from core with no change.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Works fine.

Comment: I don't get any errors, but the plugin remains activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling deactivate_plugins() from within a class, rather than the plugin file itself, which of course returned the wrong location for **FILE**

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SO) Self-deactivate with $_GET['my_deactivate']
 */

add_action( 'admin_init', function()
{
    if( isset( $_GET['my_deactivate'] ) )
    {
        deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), true );
        $url = admin_url( 'plugins.php?deactivate=true' );
        header( "Location: $url" );
        die();
    }
});
```

After activating, enter any admin URL adding `?my_deactivate`, e.g.:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/users.php?my_deactivate
```

<sub>Reference:</sub>

- [*Function deactivate_plugins does not exist*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/18539/12615)

Comment: Put this inside of the deactivate_plugin function and it didn't work for me. In fact, the if statement is never called because there's no my_deactivate variable passed through GET. Changing that variable to 'activate' still doesn't produce the desired result. All WP plugins disabled, running stock WP4.0.

Comment: That deactivation notice fires, but the plugin deactivation doesn't work after several variations.

Comment: Tested in WP3.9 as well, no luck.

Comment: Is that the main plugin file? How are you instantiating the class?

Comment: That's in the class. instantiating like so: require_once( 'inc/class/tt-ve.class.php' );
$tt_ve   = new TT_VideoElements( 'localizationDomain' );
Thanks for your help

Comment: Probably `plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), true )` is pointing to the wrong file.